# How to fill an air gap under vinyl flooring?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I installed vinyl plank flooring, and a hump in the concrete caused an air gap underneath the planks near it.

How can I fill that void/gap without tearing out the whole floor?

Is there some kind of injection I could use to fill it?

Comment: It's a floating floor...right?  It will go down much faster the 2nd time!

Comment: Yes I can put down a ridiculous amount of that stuff in a day.  Levelling concrete is actually a challenge when there's nothing on top of it, so you should probably pull the floor and put it back down after you level the concrete.  If you want a sloppy/risky solution, yes there is some chance you could drill a hole or many holes and pour or inject some sort of filler, but most of the materials you could use are adhesive, so when it doesn't work out well enough you'll have an even bigger cleanup before you can re-lay the floor.

Comment: If you pull the floor, keep the cut pieces organized so you don't have to search around for the right piece when you reinstall.  A flat rolling cart is a huge aid if you have to pull a floor.  Even just a piece of plywood with castor wheels on it.

Comment: If it is only one or two small bumps, try using a hairdryer to soften the vinyl, then press it firmly by hand (with the working glove on or cloth).

Comment: Is the depression enough that joints open when you step it down? If not, don't worry about it. It'll settle on its own over time.

Comment: A Hump? It may be better to grind it down rather then try to fill all around it. Or a combination of the two.

Comment: @r13 wouldn't that end up translating the bump into the finished floor, creating a potential trip hazard in addition to looking bad?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, it can. Depending on the size/area of the hump, The method I provided can result in a small raise/protrusion on the floor that is uncomfortable to step on; or become a hump similar to street bumps. Anything that protrudes above the floor can be an eyesore and hazardous, it is up to the owner to decide either to live with it or spend $$ to correct it.